# How to search a specific data in sorted list or given data?

Tags: python, sortedlist

```
def BinarySearch(data_of_xyz, search_key):
    low_indx = 0
    hig_indx = len(data_of_xyz) -1
    found = False
    while low_indx<=hig_indx and not found:
        mid_indx = (low_indx + hig_indx) // 2
        if search_key == data_of_xyz[mid_indx]:
            found = True
        elif search_key > data_of_xyz[mid_indx]:
            low_indx = mid_indx + 1
        else:
            hig_indx = mid_indx - 1
    if found == True:
        print("Your search key is at position: ")
    else:
        print("Your key is not found: ")

data_of_xyz = [13, 24, 32, 35, 78]
data_of_xyz.sort()
print(data_of_xyz)
search_key = int(input("Enter the required key: "))
BinarySearch(data_of_xyz,search_key)
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the required key: 35
Your search key is at position:
```

if you see it doesn't show 35 position from the list!

Comment: Isn't easier to have `found = data_of_xyz.index(search_key) if search_key in data_of_xyz else None`? Or you just wanted to know if your implementation of the search function is right?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. How do you think `if found == True:` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't print the value because you told it to print only the header text, not the value.

```
if found:
    print("Your search key is at position: ", mid_indx)
```

fixes the problem:

```
[13, 24, 32, 35, 78]
Enter the required key: 35
Your search key is at position:  3
```

Comment: Yes! you are right, it did worked as mentioned by you, thanks Prune!